# How to pause the application till the json data is downloaded using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, progress-bar, alamofire

I am trying to build an app where I will be using Alamofire to make a request to some 3 rd party API. One of my text fields needs to show the value I get from the response.

I have a function which takes the response from JSON and then returns a value which needs to be shown in my textField. How can i delay the textfield function, until i get my value from the response.

And can i show a progress bar or activity monitor while the data is being downloaded just to make sure that user does not think the app is doing nothing ?(During the api is being called and function is being executed)

Comment: use progressbar until you update the textfield

Comment: you can hide the textfield and show it when it becomes avaiable.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Thanks a lot, i Have used progree HUD and it works as required. Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of options:

**a.** Use an activity indicator as suggested in the comments to your question.

**b.** Use a completion handler for your call

```
func getTextFieldData(url: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://someurl.com/gettextFieldData",
                          parameters: ["queryValue": userName],
                          encoding:.JSON).responseJSON { request, response, result in

                switch (result) {
                case .Success(let JSON):
                    let fieldValue = String(data: JSON.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
                                            encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                    completion(fieldValue)
                case .Failure(let data, _):
                    if let errorData = data,
                         fieldValue = String(data: errorData,
                                             encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                        completion(fieldValue)
                    }
                }
        }
 }
```

You can update the value in the completion handler

**c.** Fetch the text field value before your present the view.

**d.** Use a default value and update it when your API call returns data.

Comment: Can someone edit this answer and format the code properly? I have tried a lot but am not able to make it look good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for this.